# series in series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ be a complex convergent series

is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n \cdot \sum_{m=n+1}^\infty a_m)$ calculable ?

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: what's happen in this case?

Comment: Are you asking if the series is convergent, or do you really want us to be able to calculate the sum?

Comment: any  information as welcome, the calculation is the best

Comment: $a:=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ => Your series is equal to $a^2-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ .

Comment: @user90369 Assuming the derivation is correct, why does the second term converge?

Comment: @user90369 thanks, but it is not useful for me because i started from that relation, it moves my problem

Comment: @MateyMath If all you have is that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then the other series can be divergent.

Comment: O.k. . Perhaps your question becomes clearer if you explain what you mean with calculation here. :-)

Comment: @DanielFischer yes you are right so i need as much information as possible

Comment: @user90369 if there's any form to exprime that by a

Comment: To express the series by $a$ ? No, I don't think so. Can you please clearify $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ ? For complex values your inequation doesn't exist. Do you mean $|\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n | < \infty$ or $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| < \infty$ ? Or something else ?

Comment: i mean convergent

Comment: Thanks! But I see *Clement C.* has answered your question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that both the following series are convergent
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^2 $$
we have the following symmetry trick:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\sum_{m>n}a_m = \sum_{1\leq n < m}a_n a_m = \sum_{1\leq m < n}a_n a_m = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\right)^2-\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^2\right]. $$

Comment: @MateyMath: you're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

This is not convergent in general.

- If your series is *absolutely* convergent, then indeed your new series will be absolutely convergent as well, by comparison (this is straightforward).
- Otherwise, it may not be. Consider for instance the alternating series given by the general term $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n\geq 1$. We have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, but
  $$
  \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{n}} + o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) 
  $$
  *(if I am not mistaken)*; from which you get
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_n a_k =
  -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -\infty
  $$
  by comparison.

Comment: thanks so much @Clement C.

Comment: Absolute convergence is not strictly needed, we may compute such double series under weaker assumptions, for instance $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}\in\ell^1\cap\ell^2$.

Comment: True... I didn't mean to give a full characterization, just mention that extra assumptions were needed (the simplest being absolute convergence).